# IE11 script onload not working (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, onload

I am currently working on a data-intensive web application that frequently communicates with an external API and retrieves JSONP data when returned. The script depends upon a library called head.js v1.0.3. http://headjs.com/ to accomplish this. However, I noticed that in IE 11 for some reason, the onload event for the script sometimes, but not always, fires before the script has actually loaded into the browser. The behavior is demonstrable whether using head.js or not. Alternatively, I may create a script element with the onload event set to capture the returned data. Sometimes it works, and sometimes not. Even more weird is that once it happens the first time, it seems to keep happening for the duration of the browser session.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Here is some example code:

```
//somejson.js
/*
    window["queryResult"] = {blah:'blah'}
*/

function loadScript() {
    head.load("/somejson.js", afterScriptLoad)
}

function afterScriptLoad() {
    var result = queryResult
    //Throws error because window.queryResult is sometimes undefined
}
```

Comment: Will it work when you declare `afterScriptLoad` before calling `loadScript`, or just pass it as an anonymous function?

Comment: The same thing happens with an anonymous function. I think I figured out a workaround. It's not ideal, but if it works, then I will post details later.

Comment: I also encounter the issue. It seems that cross-origin js request will not dispatch onload event in ie 11.

Comment: @cocoa My particular use case was a workaround because I could not control the CORS headers on Google hosted scripts. I had to use JSONP. If you are able to set access-control headers server-side, that might help. Then you can use JSON.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann The script onload fires normally after I added the site (where the external js is from) into Trusted Sites. I guess that this issue is related with security settings in ie 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of research, it seems the only way around this bug is to modify the API so that once the variable holding the JSONP is initialized, the script itself triggers the callback. Unfortunately, this would not work as a solution for others if they do not have access to modify whatever API is in use, but it does solve the problem for me.

```
//somejson.js
/*
    window["queryResult"] = {blah:'blah'}; scriptCallback()
*/
function loadScript(callback) {
    var c = new afterScriptLoad(callback)
    window["scriptCallback"] = c
    head.load("/somejson.js", c)
}
function afterScriptLoad(callback) {
    var retrieved = false
    return function () {
        if (!retrieved) {
            retrieved = true
            callback(queryResult)
        }
    }
}
function myCallback(response) {
    //do something
}
```